# CSS table alignment issues with columns containing long strings

Tags: css

I have a problem: my table displays perfectly without a "separator" row. This row server to separate the two sections of my table. The column in this row (colspan=2) contains a long string describing the section of the table below it. Unfortunately, the presence of this long string causes the rest of the table to become misaligned. How can I tell the table to effectively ignore this column when sizing the table, or how can I otherwise fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colgroup` and `col` tags (setting the column widths this way). And then add `table-layout: fixed;` to your table's CSS:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:25%" />
        <col style="width:25%" />
        <col style="width:25%" />
        <col style="width:25%" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <!-- thead stuff here -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- tbody stuff here -->
    </tbody>
</table>

table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. If you want to add a comment about why this solves the problem that would be helpful. Specifically why setting table-layout:fixed along with the col widths would make it work.

Comment: `table { table-layout: fixed; }` effectively disables the browser's table-layout algorithm, allowing you to (successfully) specify the column widths. Using the `colgroup` tag and child `col` tags simply makes specifying the widths easier and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the explanation.